# ggplot not plotting the values in the plot with new data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting with ggplot with the subsets of some data for ggplot to work with.
I have written out 2 of the data I want to plot

data link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1D7Z6mV3-2Sm3KK_w1s5VNyg-imDCTeBe?usp=sharing

But the problem is my ggplot is not updating the values in the plot, so the new plot generated although have different titles but the values are exactly the same as the old one.

I have tried to restarted the R but it doesnt solve the problem.

I have assigned a variable to d<- ggplot(data)

And I can see d is correctly reflecting the new data loaded, and the actually plot when I print it will update the ggtitle, so the plotting itself wasnt dead. Just for some reason whatever data I'm providing, the actual plot is always the same

```
library(ggplot2)
library(wesanderson)
d<-ggplot(C1.PDB)
pal <- wes_palette("Zissou1", 50, type = "continuous")

m <-d+
  geom_tile(aes(x=Combination, y=Drug_dose, fill=Avg.percent))+
  geom_text(aes(x=Combination, y=Drug_dose,label=Avg.percent), size=3)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors=pal)+
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size=10, face="bold", color = "black"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15,  face="bold", color = "black")) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9,  face="bold", color = "black")) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15,  face="bold", color = "black", vjust = 3))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15,  face="bold", color = "black", hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16))+
  theme(strip.text.y  = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold", color = "black"))+
  scale_x_discrete(position ="top") +
  xlab("Combination added")+
  ylab("Treatments in the screen")+
  ggtitle("Cluster 1 Enriched in PDB response")


  print(m)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. Are you loading in your two dataframes from separate .csv files?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(wesanderson)

d <- sample.data #From your googledrive

pal <- wes_palette("Zissou1", 50, type = "continuous")
m <-ggplot (data=d)+
  geom_tile(aes(x=Combination, y=Drug_dose, fill=Avg.percent))+
  geom_text(aes(x=Combination, y=Drug_dose,label=Avg.percent), size=3)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors=pal)+
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size=10, face="bold", color = "black"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15,  face="bold", color = "black")) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9,  face="bold", color = "black")) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15,  face="bold", color = "black", vjust = 3))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15,  face="bold", color = "black", hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16))+
  theme(strip.text.y  = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold", color = "black"))+
  scale_x_discrete(position ="top") +
  xlab("Combination added")+
  ylab("Treatments in the screen")+
  ggtitle("Cluster 1 Enriched in PDB response")
m
```

Comment: Willimes, you are right, I think something happened during my pivot long, all my subset data has the correct labels but  all of them have the same repeated numeric values. :( I'm an idiot

Comment: Pivot_longer can take some time to get used to. I found this helpful: https://www.riinu.me/2019/04/new-intuitive-ways-to-reshape-data-in-r/

Comment: Thank you. I made a stupid mistake, always and always check the actual data. It turned out the pivot was done correctly. What went wrong is my excel sheets reading, I need to skip lines, and my home cooked function end up just copy paste the sheet 1 for all sheets. I will need to post a seperate question for this problem